# Orphan of App Group Capabilities to share Datas between iPhone and Watch

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I need to share (read and edit) a string between iPhone and Watch apps. With WatchOS 1 and App Group Capabilities it was very easy; now I can't understand how to replace this sharing function...

Does someone knows an easy (and working) tutorial to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Watch Connectivity** instead of App Group.

watchOS 2: How to communicate between devices using Watch Connectivity | kristinathai.com http://www.kristinathai.com/watchos-2-how-to-communicate-between-devices-using-watch-connectivity/

Introducing Watch Connectivity - WWDC 2015 - Videos - Apple Developer https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=713

Watch Connectivity Framework Reference https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/index.html

Comment: I've already tried but using userInfo or applicationContext, dictionary saved with this methods are mono-use (after being read from other devices, they're destroyed), I need something which can be read without being destroyed...

Comment: Could you not just persist the contents when you receive it?